# Is there a way to use angular 2 without any module loader?

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

The Quickstart section on the [angular 2 official site](https://angular.io/) describes how to run the simpliest angular 2 application. By default [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) is used as module loader. Also there is a note, saying that there are alternatives that work just fine. I understand the benefits of module loaders, but is there a way to run angular 2 app without any module loader at all?

When I simply delete SystemJS configuration and SystemJS source script tag, I get an error in console in `angular2.dev.js` file:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

It looks like angular 2 itself uses SystemJS. So, is there a way to use angular 2 without any module loader?

Comment: I am using es6 so cant help you much since I would be building with different tools, but you should look into a tool for transcompiling all you code into a single build js file. I used browsify with babel plugin to transcompile es6 , but you should be able do browsify with a type script plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use plain ES5 javascript. Try [this simple example](http://www.angulartodo.com/index-js.html).

Also, you can try the [oficial javascript 5 min quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) where they create an example considering that "ES5 JavaScript doesn't have a native module system. There are several popular 3rd party module systems we could use. Instead, for simplicity and to avoid picking favorites, we'll create a single global namespace for our application.".

That single global namespace (and loading the correct scripts described in the tutorial (angular2-all.umd.js, etc.)) is one of the ways to run without a module loader.

This structure also works with Typescript or ES6. You only need to add your favorite transpiler ([Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel), [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler), etc.) to compile your code to ES5 and use it with the rest of the code from the tutorial, but I suppose you already have that running.

Comment: Unfortunately, both links to examples are dead now. Is there any updated version of them?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blogpost](https://medium.com/@vivainio/with-latest-typescript-you-may-not-need-webpack-417d2ef0e773#.ij7w50yoe) you can use the TypeScript compiler to traverse the imports and bundle them. The feature in question is [Concatenate AMD and System modules with --outFile](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#concatenate-amd-and-system-modules-with---outfile). I have not tested this. Technically SystemJS is still a module loader but it is supposed to be standardized.