# 3rd Party module system for Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following the [official guide](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) of Angular 2 with JavaScript (not TypeScript), at the beginning of the guide, under the "Modules" sub-heading, it is written that:

> "ES5 JavaScript doesn't have a native module system. There are several
> popular 3rd party module systems we could use. Instead, for simplicity
> and to avoid picking favorites, we'll create a single global namespace
> for our application."

and the code for a basic application is this:

```
(function(app) {
  app.AppComponent =
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {}
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Since I'm not a professional JavaScript coder, I wonder how we can use a 3rd party module system instead of `(function(app){})();` (or not instead of?)
Give me some examples of 3rd party module system with this code modified, please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to the [demo](http://www.angulartodo.com/index-js.html)

and also view this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956609/is-there-a-way-to-use-angular-2-without-any-module-loader)